# How to translate the metasyntactic variables “foo” and “bar” in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

In programming, English speaking people often use *foo* and *bar* as [metasyntactic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) to name things that they don't want to name.

What do French-speaking people use and why?

---

En programmation, les anglophones utilisent fréquemment *foo* et *bar* comme [variables métasyntaxiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_m%C3%A9tasyntaxique) pour nommer les choses qu'ils ne veulent pas nommer.

Qu'est-ce que les francophones utilisent et pourquoi?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In French programming, I have seen several tendencies

- The most common is to use *toto*, *titi*, *tata* or *azerty*
- A relevant placeholder name, like *Tartempion* for a last name, *Pierre* or *Marie* for a first name
- In mathematics-related programming, *f*, *x*, *i* and so on with usual mathematical variables
- In English-speaking circles, *foo*, *bar* and *baz*
- And of course, among Pythonista, *spam*, *eggs*, *sausages* and *spam*

---

En programmation française, j'ai vu plusieurs tendances

- Le plus commun est d'utiliser *toto*, *titi*, *tata* or *azerty*
- Un nom *ad hoc*, comme *Tartempion* pour un surnom, *Pierre* ou *Marie* pour un prénom
- En programmation orientée  mathématiques, *f*, *x*, *i*, etc., les variables mathématiques habituelles
- Chez les anglophones, *foo*, *bar*, et *baz*
- Et bien sûr, pour les Pythonista, *spam, eggs, sausages and spam*

Answer (score 2):

*Truc*, *bidule*, *machin* and *chose*. They are usually preceded by a definite article (most of the time “le”) and can mean anything. Typically:

> — Tu me passes le truc sur la table ?
>   — Ouais. Euh, c'est quoi ce machin ?

To name persons we don't know or remember the name, among those, *bidule*, *machin* or *trucmuche* are the most commonly used. Another possibility is to choose a random very (un)common name.

As variable names or as garbage data, *tata*, *titi*, *toto* or *tutu* may also come handy, but those would not be used in spoken language.

---

*Truc*, *bidule*, *machin* et *chose*. Ils sont précédées par un article défini (habituellement « le ») et peuvent désigner n'importe quoi.  Typiquement :

> — Tu me passes le truc sur la table ?
>   — Ouais. Euh, c'est quoi ce machin ?

Pour nommer les personnes dont on ne connait pas le nom — aussi utile si on ne s'en souvient pas — *bidule*, *machin*, ou *trucmuche* sont les plus communs.  Une autre possibilité est de choisir un nom au hasard très (peu) commun.

En tant que noms de variables ou données jetables, *tata*, *titi*, *toto*, ou *tutu* peuvent être utiles aussi, mais on ne les utiliserait pas dans la langue parlée.

Comment: Duh, (sadly) the question was specifically about programming. I realise it only now.

Answer (score 2):

Les usages diffèrent, on a de nombreuses variantes, et pour cause : par définition ce choix est totalement arbitraire. Le nommage n'a pas, au contraire des variables qui seront réellement utilisées dans le code en production, de contraintes spécifiques de clarté ou de cohérence globale.

Pourquoi vouloir traduire et fixer ces termes ? Quelle valeur ajoutée cela apporterait-il, par rapport à l'invention pure et simple de termes, eux-aussi totalement arbitraires ?

Un lecteur anglophone serait-il choqué de lire un morceau de code générique, employant des variables d'example qui seraient autres que *foo*, *bar* et *baz* ? Comprendrait-il moins bien ? J'en doute.

Un peu de créativité que diable ! (ce en quoi je plussoie allègrement [la proposition *spamesque* d'Evpok](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4654/82))

---

The usages differ; we have numerous variants, and with good reason: by definition, this choice is totally arbitrary.  The naming doesn't, unlike variables that will really be used in production code, have specific constraints of clarity or global coherence.

Why do you want to translate and fix these terms?  What added value would be brought by that, rather than purely and simply inventing terms, themselves totally arbitrary?

Would an anglophone reader be shocked to read a piece of generic code that used example variables other than *foo*, *bar*, and *baz*?  Would they understand it less well?  I doubt it.

A bit of creativity, damn it! (in this vein I verily agree with [Evpok's spammy proposal](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4654/82))

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question.

Comment: Ma réponse à la question est celle-ci : *tout* mot est ici une bonne traduction.

Comment: Ça c'est (presque) une réponse, mais est-ce que ça traduit vraiment une particularité francophone, j'en doute.

Answer (score 2):

Toto et Tutu sont mes préférés. Même s'il s'agit surtout de préférence personnelle, beaucoup de programmeurs (web à tout le moins) utilisent Toto.

Une bonne traduction doit être invisible au lecteur. Le couple foo/bar est trop loin de l'utilisation de tous les jours pour un programmeur francophone, et partant, trop artificiel.

---

Toto and Tutu are my preferences.  Even if it's just personal preference, many programmers (web at least) use Toto.

A good translation should be invisible to the reader.  The foo/bar couple is too far from everyday usage of a French programmer, and hence too artificial.

Comment: A chaque fois qu'un développeur utilise *toto* pour ne pas avoir à clarifier sa démarche intellectuelle, un petit chaton est assassiné.

Comment: L'utilité d'un Toto tient surtout dans le fait qu'on sait toujours quel nom saugrenu chercher pour supprimer dans le code après une phase de débogage. D'ailleurs, il sert avant tout de marqueur positionnel de code de test (appeler une variable toto serait un brin trop embrouillant).

Comment: Hélas, on en a tous (trop) vu en guise de variables de test, et (beaucoup trop) souvent aussi qui restaient en place dans le code définitif de production... déprimant mais tellement réel.